# Is there any way to create space for a variable name within the var declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I don't work with JavaScript, but I'm trying to find this answer. We want to change the _ within variable names into space. I know JavaScript does not allow this, but is there a clever way of doing this like concatenating the two into one such as:

```
var firstname + ' ' + lastname
```

Then put

```
firstname lastname = "Jack Jill";
```

Or perhaps some library calls. I know the above does not  work because of + and '

Comment: `let [firstname, lastname] = "Jack Jill".split(" ");`

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding the question. Do you want a variable that contains a concatenation of two strings, eg `firstName = "Jack"; lastName = "Jill"; fullName=firstName+lastName;` or are you trying to declare a variable called `firstName lastName`? If the latter, you cannot do that (to my knowledge) in javascript. Whitespace is not valid in identifiers. Probably just use `snakeCase`, eg `firstNameLastName`

Comment: It is a whole set of column names that the client wants changed, their preference

Comment: I doubt your client cares if your variable names use a space or an underscore...

Comment: @CollinD yes is the later that I want to do and javascript does not allow. Wonder if anyone may have come up  with  a clever hack

Comment: Exactly, the variable name itself shouldn't really matter only the value

Comment: I suspect that what you actually want is not what you're asking for, or what the client actually wants. Can you describe the problem a little better?

Comment: @kevbuntu If there is a "hack" it would be transpilation, which then takes this out of the realm of javascript. Your question, as asked, has a concrete answer. Javascript does not allow identifiers of that nature.

Comment: @CollinD oh well, unfortunately not :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

As you need variable name to be spaced not value.
You can add it to context e.g.

context is window/this/xyz

```
window[firstname+' '+lastname] = "Jack Jill";
this[firstname+' '+lastname] = "Jack Jill";
xyz[firstname+' '+lastname] = "Jack Jill";
```

But while consuming it you have to use in similar(above) faison you can't use them directly as you can consume other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as follows:

```js
var firstName = "Jack";
var lastName = "Jill";

var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

console.log(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces themselves are not a valid character for variable names, you should use underscores instead.

If you are looking to add a space between some variables you can do it by combining variables as shown below:

```
//Declare 2 variables
var firstName = 'kev';
var lastName = 'buntu';

//Declare variable to combine the two and add a space
var fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;

//Print the combined variable to verify the result
//should display "kev buntu"
console.log(fullName)
```

edit: given the OP's answers in comments it appears that this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/620197), so potentially the solution is just creating a set of display text variables rather than directly using internal variable names as display values.

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, 'no', there is no way to make a variable name with a space in it. This is not valid javascript.

You can make an object key with a space in it, by wrapping it in quotes, but I would avoid that if possible, and I don't think that's what you want anyway.

```
let obj = {
  "firstname lastname": "John Doe"
}
```

You should stick with camel_case or snakeCase and furthermore, your variable names shouldn't be surfaced to the user (or client), so this shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

For sure that's possible:

Using other whitespace than space, here [U+3164](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3164)

```js
let firstNameﾠsecondName = "You See";
console.log(firstNameﾠsecondName);
```

There are multiple whitespaces in Unicode, just one of them is used by JS to separate identifiers. But please, *don't do this*.

Comment: Is firstName secondName the name of one variable now? can I do firstName SecondName="I see". I am trying an online js editor but nothing is printed to it

Comment: Please answer the comments of Brett East under your question.